# How to redirect dd progress in terminal to a log file after replacing carriage returns with newline characters

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, stdout, dd

Any idea why this command isn't working?

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress |& tr '\r' '\n' >> test.txt`

I want the contents of test.txt to look something like this.

```
395191296 bytes (395 MB, 377 MiB) copied, 1 s, 395 MB/s
805187584 bytes (805 MB, 768 MiB) copied, 2 s, 403 MB/s
1239563264 bytes (1.2 GB, 1.2 GiB) copied, 3 s, 413 MB/s
1666015232 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 4 s, 417 MB/s
```

Right now the command is printing nothing to test.txt

Comment: Adding `2>&1` before pipe and removing **&** should resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because of `tr` wait for its job finish, which will take an infinite time.

`unbuffer` can help you in this situation:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress |& unbuffer -p tr '\r' '\n' >>test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. Although I didn't want to install the `expect` package, so I tried looking for an alternative to `unbuffer` and found the `stdbuf` command.

Ended up using this command in the end 

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress |& stdbuf -oL -eL tr '\r' '\n' >>test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

**Use tee**
Eg:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress 2>&1 | tee test
```

Then you can replace \r with \n OR open with `nano`

Comment: use `tee -a test` to append to the file